# How to declare and store data in a variable number of variables?

Tags: c++

Im new to coding and I have to create a game through C++ on the terminal. I am taking the input of the number of players and for instance x players are playing. Then, I want x number of strings that store the players name and I want to use that variable repeatedly each time it is their turn. Can someone guide me as to how to do this?

I tried creating a void function but I was not sure what do with it.

Comment: read about `std::vector`

Comment: there are more containers, but roughly 95% of the time you just want a `std::vector`

Comment: @JasonLIam "any good c++ book" -> "any good c++ introductory book"

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Yes agreed in this case "introductory" books is all the OP needs. All introductory books will explain the concept of arrays(and then vectors hopefully).

Answer (score 3):

Something along the lines:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct Player {
    std::string name;
    int score;
    // other player's data
};

int main() {
    int nplayers;
    std::vector<Player> players;
    
    std::cout << "how many players ? ";
    std::cin >> nplayers;

    players.resize(nplayers);

    for (int i=0; i<nplayers; ++i) {
        std::cout << "player's " << i+1 << " name? ";
        std::cin >> players[i].name;
    }
    
    // ...
}
```